# getting and setting socket options in Tornado

Tags: python, sockets, tornado

I wonder how I can run tornado web application using regular sockets, so that I can access each socket directly for getsockopt/setsockopt. Basically, what I want to do is to get tcp_info of the listening sockets.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
from tornado import httpserver, ioloop, netutil, web


class MainHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")


application = web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

sockets = netutil.bind_sockets(8888)
for s in sockets:
    print s

server = httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
server.add_sockets(sockets)
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
application.listen(8888)
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

More info is in [the HTTPServer docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html), in the section about "advanced multi-process".

Comment: Hey @Amir, is there more info you need or will you accept my answer as correct?